# Calculating hourly temperature from Min and Max temp

Tags: max, min, temperature, calculation, hour

Is there a method to calculate the hourly temperature by knowing the Max and Min temperature of that day?

I already have the daily min and max and would like to calculate the approximate hourly (12:00 am to 11:59 pm) temperature from these data

we know that the maximum temperature is around noon time (12:00 pm). However, how to calculate for the rest of the hours of the day (1:00 pm, 3:00 pm, 6:00 pm, 10 pm ...etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am against this idea, but here is what one could do if one really wanted:

Get data on temperature distribution over the day (this will probably be different depending on season, location etc.). Weather stations provide this data I would assume.
Train a [gaussian process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) using this data.

Input the maximal and minimal values into your process where the model says the maximum / minimum typically is (probably not at noon / midnight!), then sample the process. I don't know how this is done, but there are probably software packages for that. If you sample enough, you will have a distribution of the hourly values and can say how likely a temperature is going to be (according to your model) at hour x.